# MYSQL can't load character into set

Tags: mysql, set

I have this file:

```
1.nothing
2.o,s,f,d
3.f,d
4.o,s
5.s,f,d
6.s
7.nothing
8.s,f,d
9.o,d
10.s,f
```

And a table:

```
describe delete_me;
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| privileges | set('o','s','f','d') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I try to:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'privileges.txt' INTO TABLE delete_me FIELDS TERMINATED BY '.';
```

I get this:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | privileges |
+------+------------+
|    0 |            |
|    2 | f,s,o      |
|    3 | f          |
|    4 | o          |
|    5 | f,s        |
|    6 |            |
|    7 |            |
|    8 | f,s        |
|    9 | o          |
|   10 | s          |
|   11 | o          |
|   12 |            |
|   13 | o          |
|   14 | o          |
|   15 | s          |
|   16 |            |
|   17 | o          |
|   18 | o          |
|   19 | s,o        |
|   20 | f          |
+------+------------+
```

The letter `d` just disappears. Why?

Comment: Not sure I can say why, but you should note that it is not the letter 'd' specifically; but the last set item listed (note that 6 is also empty, having lost its only value 's')

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now i see

Comment: But still cant understand why last symbol in the string are dissapears.

Comment: I'm not sure either; perhaps if you had a `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause, the issue would resolve iteself. _The default is a non-printing character that perhaps is not used by your source file._

Comment: I used LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'. It's doesnt help. I solve this problem just by using numbers like 1,2,3,4... not strings. I dont understand why strings are not works correctly. if i create  varchar type field and load file into varchar table all is Ok, but when i INSERT this varchar type into set field have the same problem: last character is dissapears..